# React-Leaflet: Polyline does not change colour despite colour value in Redux store updating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have setup a Redux store which contains a hex colour code. I plan to implement a function where users can select a colour which the line will appear as. However, when the I used the selector to update the color prop of the polyline, the line on the map itself does not change colour. I have already verified the redux store is working fine.

```
const DashboardLineAnimation: React.FC<Props> = (): ReactElement => {

    const [start, setStart] = useState([0, 0]);
    const [end, setEnd] = useState([45, 45]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={() => {setStart([start[0] + 10, start[1] + 10])}}></input>
            <Polyline color={useSelector((state: RootState): string => state.attackMap.options.color.hex)} positions={[start as LatLngTuple, end as LatLngTuple]} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the documented prop `pathOptions` which is an object the property `color` on that object and change the value of that property. `color` prop is available but normally it should be immutable as it is not documented on the [official docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#polyline) while `pathOptions` is documented as mutable, thus can be changed.

Also make sure the `Polyline` is a child of MapContainer when you use it. Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-polyline-does-not-change-colour-new6t?file=/src/App.js:175-191) without using redux with a local state variable

```
function App() {
  ...
  const [color, setColor] = useState("blue");

  const handleClick = () => setColor("red");

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change polyline color</button>
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Polyline pathOptions={{ color }} positions={polyline} />
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```